# The steps required and technical to build the following addon

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon, xul

I would like to build an addon with basic functions:

- get text (A) from page ( Visit http://facebook.com, http://youtube.com etc ) like comments.
- call the web service function process this text (A) and return another text (B)
- replace (A) by (B) and show it for user

This is basic idea of my addon.

But I don't know the steps required and technical to build it. please help me clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [page-mod](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-mod.html) so a script is triggered when landing on specific pages (Facebook, Youtube), that can communicate the data (comments) to the `main` script so that it can send it off to the external server with something like [net/xhr](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/net/xhr.html). Preserving the requests with the DOM elements would be necessary, so that on response, the main script can communicate back with the page-mod worker to replace the response text with the corresponding DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

With the firefox-addon-sdk, there is video from a tutorial where it is accomplished something similar to what you are talking about, but it was with the google translate api: See it [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKN4_fOKEWQ)

In XUL, first you'll need to put together the basic structure of an extension. See [here](http://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/) for a good place to start.

Then you can get the text by selecting it, and clicking an item in the context menu ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/PopupGuide/Extensions#Modifying_the_context_menu)):

```
<popup id="contentAreaContextMenu">
    <menuitem id="yourMenuItem" 
              label="Name of your service" 
              insertafter="context-selectall" 
              oncommand="yourFunction();" />
</popup>
```

that when clicked will get the content of the selection ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getSelection)):

```
var selectedText = doc.getSelection().toString();

alert(selectedText);
```

The you call your webservice via xmlhttprequest ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/XMLHttpRequest/Usar_XMLHttpRequest)) and when the response comes, you change the selected text to the one your server returns:

```
// textToReplace is the text that will replace the currently selected text
var doc = gBrowser.contentDocument;

var sel, range;
sel = doc.getSelection();
if (sel.rangeCount) {
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    range.deleteContents();
    range.insertNode(doc.createTextNode(textToReplace));
}
```

You still have to do a lot of validations, but this is about what you need to do.